# Insulating state and quantum Hall state

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, topological-phase

So, in many papers, I found this intuitive illustration and I have a problem with understanding it.

So, as I understand in the insulating state, we consider a system and there are electrons that move in a circular orbit around some atom (red in the picture). And below, in the quantum Hall state, there are similar circular orbits but they are caused by a magnetic field. What is more, on the edges, the electron "bounces" from the edge which leads to skipping orbits.

So I have two questions about that picture:

1. What will happen if we move the red dots down in the first picture? Why it doesn't bounce off the edge like in the quantum Hall state?
2. What happened with"the red dots" in the second picture?

[image: illustration]